# Separate launch images for iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, info.plist

I'm working on an update to bring my iPhone app to iPad. (to make it a universal app)
Currently I have the following launch images:

```
Default.png - 320 x 480 px
Default@2x.png - 640 x 960 px
Default-568h@2x.png - 640 x 1136 px
Default-667h@2x.png - 750 x 1334 px
Default-736h@3x.png - 1242 x 2208 px
```

Do I need to add separate launch images for the iPad?
The app should support all devices with iOS 8 and is currently *portrait mode* only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need add separate launch images for the iPad.
As you support only portrait mode you need add only two images:
1. `Default~ipad.png` 1024x768 px
2. `Default@2x~ipad.png` 2048x1536 px

Also you can use alternative way for launch images: `LaunchScreen.xib` (Xcode -> File -> New -> File... -> User Interface -> LaunchScreen).
It's suitable way when your launch screen can be built in interface builder. It will allow avoid storing multiple launch images in the project, so it makes your app thinner.